# Nonclustered index on varchar column or partitioned table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (
   ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   TextField varchar(100)
)
```

I have nonclustered index on `TextField` column.

I am creating a simple query which selects both columns and in where condition i have next situation:

```
...
WHERE SUBSTRING(TextField, 1, 1) = 'x'
```

Is it better to convert query to `LIKE` condition with 'x%' or to create partition function on `TextField` column.

How partitioning can affect on search condition over varchar column, and what solution will be better for large amount of rows?

Comment: Tell me what other columns will be used from `dbo.Table1` ? Describe a **tipical** query based on `SUBSTRING(TextField, 1, 1) = 'x'` predicate.

Comment: Are you always going to be searching on the first letter of the TextField column?  In other words, you won't be searching for the second letter or some piece in the middle?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean There will be used only two columns, which are defined in table. tipical query will be `SELECT * FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE SUBSTRING(TextFields, 1, 1) = 'x'`

Comment: @StuartAinsworth Yes, I wil be only searching words with certain first character

Comment: What other columns have this table (tell me the data type for every column) ?

Comment: Let's say that beside mentioned columns, I have another one `Description varchar(100) not null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default ,`SUBSTRING(TextField, 1, 1) = 'x'` is not `SARG`able.

First, I would **test** that query with following solutions (SQL Profiler > {SQLStatement|Batch} Completed > CPU,Reads,Writes,Duration columns):

**1)** A non-clustered index on `TextField` column:

```
CREATE INDEX IN_Table1_TextField
ON dbo.Table1(TextField)
INCLUDE(non-indexed columns); -- See `SELECT` columns
GO
```

And the query should use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT ... FROM TextField LIKE 'x%'; -- Where "x" represent one or more chars.
```

Pros/cons: B-Tree/index will have many levels because o key length (maximum 100 chars + RowID if isn't a UNIQUE index) .

**2)** I would create an computed column for the first char:

```
-- TextField column needs to be mandatory
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1
ADD FirstChar AS (CONVERT(CHAR(1),SUBSTRING(TextField,1,1))); -- This computed column could be non-persistent
GO
```

plus

```
CREATE INDEX IN_Table1_FirstChar
On dbo.Table1(FirstChar)
INCLUDE (non-indexed columns); 
GO
```

In this case, the predicate could be

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(TextField, 1, 1) = 'x'
```

or

```
WHERE FirstChar = 'x'
```

Pros/cons: B-Tree/index will have far less levels because o key length (1 char + RowID). I would use if predicate selectivity is high (small number of rows verifies) but without covered columns (see `INCLUDE` clause).

**3)** A *clustered* index on `FirstChar` column thus:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (
   ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
   TextField varchar(100) NOT NULL, -- This column needs to be mandatory
   ADD FirstChar AS (CONVERT(CHAR(1),SUBSTRING(TextField,1,1))),
   UNIQUE CLUSTERED(FirstChar,ID) 
);
```

In this case, the predicate could be

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(TextField, 1, 1) = 'x'
```

or

```
WHERE FirstChar = 'x'
```

Pros/cons: should give you good performance if you have many rows. In this case, the B-Tree levels will minimum (1 `CHAR` + 1 `INT`) or minimum->medium.

Answer (score 1):

Your non-clustered index can not be utilized if there is a function applied to the column (i.e. SUBSTRING).  LIKE 'x%' would be preferable here.

Comment: I know that string function prevent SQL to use nonclustered index, but whether using partitioning can additionally improve query